# Removing a widget from its wxPython parent

Tags: python, wxpython

The following program has a memory leak (I verified this on a linux system, with the `top` command)

```
import wx
from random import randint

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self,parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
    self._parent = parent
    self._nb_buttons = 0
    self._main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self._ctrl_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self._btns_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self._btn_tim = wx.Button(self,label="Start auto")
    self._btn_tim.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStartStopEvent)
    self._ctrl_sizer.Add(self._btn_tim, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5 )
    self._main_sizer.Add(self._ctrl_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER )
    self._main_sizer.Add(self._btns_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL,10)
    self.SetSizer(self._main_sizer)
    self._timer1 = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self._timer1)
    self._timer_running = False

  def OnStartStopEvent(self,event):
    if self._timer_running:    # toggle state of Timer
      self._timer1.Stop()
      self._btn_tim.SetLabel("Start")
      self._timer_running = False
    else:
      self._timer1.Start(200,False)
      self._btn_tim.SetLabel("Stop")
      self._timer_running = True

  def AddWidget(self):
    self._nb_buttons += 1 
    label = "Button %d" % self._nb_buttons
    name = "button%d" % self._nb_buttons
    new_button = wx.Button(self,label=label, name=name)
    self._btns_sizer.Add( new_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self._parent._my_sizer.Layout()
    self._parent.Fit()

  def RemoveWidget(self):
    if self._btns_sizer.GetChildren():
      self._btns_sizer.Hide(self._nb_buttons -1 )
      self._btns_sizer.Remove(self._nb_buttons -1 )
      self._nb_buttons -= 1
      self._parent._my_sizer.Layout()
      self._parent.Fit()

  def OnTimer(self,event):
    n = randint(-3,3)
    if self._nb_buttons < 2: n += randint(0,2)
    if self._nb_buttons > 10: n -= randint(0,3)
    while n > 0:
      self.AddWidget()
      n -= 1
    while n < 0:
      self.RemoveWidget()
      n += 1

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=None, title="Add remove buttons")
    self._my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    panel1 = MyPanel(self)
    self._my_sizer.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self._my_sizer)
    self.Fit()
    self.Show()

def main():
  app = wx.App(False)
  frame1 = MyFrame()
  app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The problem is that in `RemoveWidget`, the button is removed from the `Sizer`, but not from the parent `wx.Panel`.

What is the way to remove the `wx.Button` from the parent (`wx.Panel` in this case)?

When I searched for  "remove wxPython widget", the answers I found only told how to remove from sizers.  (In fact, my code is a variation from http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/05/wxpython-adding-and-removing-widgets-dynamically/ ).

There is a `RemoveChild`  method in the `wx.Window` class, but documentation says it is internal and should not be called by user code (https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.RemoveChild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I'm on windows 10, but I observed the same memory leak. Modifying the RemoveWidget method to this solved it on my computer.
See code comments for an explanation

**Edited to reflect inputs from RobinDunn**

```
def RemoveWidget(self):
    if self._btns_sizer.GetChildren():
        # GetItem returns a SizerItem, to get the actual button we have to call GetWindow
        window = self._btns_sizer.GetItem(self._nb_buttons - 1).GetWindow()
        # Calling Destroy removes widget from parent and sizer
        window.Destroy()
        self._nb_buttons -= 1
        self._parent._my_sizer.Layout()
        self._parent.Fit()
```

Comment: Widgets will remove themselves from the sizer when they are destroyed, so yes, it is redundant.  Also, widgets will remove themselves from the parent's child list, so calling `RemoveChild` is also redundant.  IOW, the call to `window.Destroy()` will be sufficient to remove the widget and its resources, and to do the necessary clean-ups in the parent and the sizer.

Comment: Checked your code in linux (raspbian): no memory leak either.